# Ubuntu not showing recovery menu

Tags: boot, grub2, login, recovery-mode, password-recovery

I'm new to Linux (Ubuntu) and forgot my administrative (main login) password.
Now also my computer won't even login the regular user.
The hard drive light is not flashing, it's dark.
The screen shows only blank purple color, nothing else, no mouse pointer no nothing.

I can only restart with the main power button, by holding it down to power off, then power back on.
If I then select *Restart* (before logging in), hold the Esc key, I get the *Advanced options* menu.

When selecting *Ubuntu with Linux 4.15.0-45-generic (recovery mode)*, a ton of text scrolls across the screen, but then does not, as I would expect, show the 'Recovery menu', but shows the user menu instead.
I read many posts online, but none seem to describe the issue where the Recovery menu doesn't show up, but still shows a normal Ubuntu screen with the users that are setup on it.

I need to reset my administrative password in order to regain access to my account.

Selecting recovery mode:

[image: selecting recovery mode]

Boot messages:

[image: boot messages]

Just before it kicks back to the login screen:

[image: just before it kicks back to the login screen]

Comment: Can you add an image of what you see on the screen?

Comment: ...it goes from Advanced Options menu to tons of commands scrolling over the screen, to ... not the recovery menu, but the log in screen.I have attached some screen pictures. Hope that helps.

Comment: Karel, Being new here I was unable to figure out how to add pictures to my post, even when reading the help and FAQ pages...I was only able to it by answering myself...as crazy as that sounds.  Thanks for correcting my post, I appreciate that.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but difference is that in my case it only stuck to command scrolling screen not going any further. Please let me know how to fix this. @OmeWillem